# Error "/bin/false: No such file or directory" on Renci.SshNet

Tags: c#, linux, unix, sftp, ssh.net

Need to connect SFTP server from c# function to execute some basic command on it, example total file count in the particular folder, every time I try to connect, connection succeed but at the time of command execution it is saying error "/bin/false: No such file or directory" . But the same folder structure "/home/adminsftp/test1" is present as confirm from FileZilla.

I am using  Renci.SshNet to connect and execute command. Please find the below code snippet for reference.

Server Connection Initialization :

```
         ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo("serverrname", 22, "keybased",
            new AuthenticationMethod[]{
                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("keybased",new PrivateKeyFile[]{
                new PrivateKeyFile("keyfile","key")
            }),
          }
```

Command execution :

```
         using (var sshclient1 = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
        {
            sshclient1.Connect();               
            using (var cmd = sshclient1.CreateCommand("cd /home/adminsftp/test1 && ls | wc -l")
            {
                cmd.Execute();
            }
         }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: For the account  that you're logging into on "serverrname", what shell is it set to use? What is in the startup files (.profile, .bash_profile, and so on) for the account?

Comment: Can you execute some simpler command, like `ls /`?

Comment: Are you able to execute the same command manually on specified server, using any SFTP client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes I tried, but no luck.

Comment: @VillageTech Yes I am able to access that server from FileZilla, able to create new files inside the folder , but not sure like how to execute same command through sftp client.

Comment: @Kenster , Thanks for replying. I don't have much idea regarding SFTP server, maintained by some other team. Any particular question I need to ask them, or can I see these .profile, startup those details by logged in through putty. Please let me know. Thanks again for your response. – Basudeb Banerjee

Comment: @BasudebBanerjee Can you give more information? *"No luck"* is rather unspecific.

Comment: @MartinPrikry l have tried with all the simple command like ls -l, but it is not working.

Comment: Thank you all, at last I solve this problem by using WINSCP library , it is working fine now.

Comment: @BasudebBanerjee If you have a solution, please post it as an answer.